# Is there a way to bulk update records in SQL based on business requirements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, gaps-and-islands, database-cursor

Attach is an image of a hard case that I am trying to figure out how to update admission date and discharge date [Example records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqhsJ.png).

| BEN_ID | CLAIM_ID | DTE_ADMISSION | DTE_DISCHARGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C0369B1C-0197-4C43-B048-1E299767C2E8 | 5685638D-412D-4D2E-9BEF-AF4C2A18F885 | 7/10/18 | 7/24/18 |
| C0369B1C-0197-4C43-B048-1E299767C2E8 | E65085AF-DAD9-4AC4-9AA6-A887D3606571 | 7/24/2018 | 7/24/2018 |
| C0369B1C-0197-4C43-B048-1E299767C2E8 | E8859A25-11D0-416F-BC1C-048451F14B4C | 7/24/2018 | 8/2/2018 |
| C0369B1C-0197-4C43-B048-1E299767C2E8 | 6608CF05-B135-40A2-9DBE-7CD3CF4F804E | 9/27/2018 | 10/4/2018 |
| C0369B1C-0197-4C43-B048-1E299767C2E8 | 4A380669-F5F6-4A62-8A44-8F53C2A6068D | 10/4/2018 | 10/8/2018 |

Here is the business requirements:

An inpatient discharge on June 1, followed by an admission to another
inpatient setting on June 1, is a direct transfer.

An inpatient discharge on June 1, followed by an admission to an
inpatient setting on June 2, is a direct transfer.

An inpatient discharge on June 1, followed by an admission to another
inpatient setting on June 3, is not a direct transfer; these are two
distinct inpatient stays.

If a claim meets the business requirements, then the first claim admission date will be "Index Admission Date", and the last claim discharge date will be "Index Discharge Date"

Based on the picture and business requirements, I want to update admission date of row 2 and 3 to July 10, 2018 as Index Admission Date and discharge date of row 1 and row 2 to August 2, 2018. The same logic applies to row 4 and 5. This is an example but the DB consists multiple record like this so I tried to use cursor but it didn't work and update the wrong date when there are more than 3 claims as row 1 to 3. Open to other suggestions as I am relatively new to SQL.
The DB is highly denormalized so there is no primary keys. After running the cursor I run the second code sample to update.

```
DECLARE @Id NUMERIC(18,0) -- database name
DECLARE @BEN_ID uniqueidentifier -- database name
DECLARE @CLAIM_ID uniqueidentifier -- path for backup files
DECLARE @DTE_ADMISSION datetime -- filename for backup
DECLARE @DTE_DISCHARGE datetime -- filename for backup

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT a.Id, a.BEN_ID, a.CLAIM_ID, a.DTE_ADMISSION, a.DTE_DISCHARGE
FROM MOCK_DATA_CLAIM a
ORDER BY a.DTE_ADMISSION ASC

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Id, @BEN_ID, @CLAIM_ID, @DTE_ADMISSION, @DTE_DISCHARGE  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

 DECLARE @COUNT INT
 SET @COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MOCK_DATA_CLAIM d
 WHERE d.BEN_ID = @BEN_ID
 AND d.CLAIM_ID <> @CLAIM_ID
 AND ABS( DATEDIFF(DAY, d.DTE_ADMISSION, @DTE_DISCHARGE) ) < 2 )
 IF (@COUNT > 0)
 BEGIN

UPDATE MOCK_DATA_CLAIM
SET MOCK_DATA_CLAIM.DTE_DISCHARGE_UPDATE = b.DTE_DISCHARGE, MOCK_DATA_CLAIM.ID_UPDATE_DTE_DIS = b.Id
FROM MOCK_DATA_CLAIM
INNER JOIN MOCK_DATA_CLAIM b ON b.BEN_ID = @BEN_ID
AND ABS( DATEDIFF(DAY, MOCK_DATA_CLAIM.DTE_DISCHARGE, b.DTE_ADMISSION) ) < 2
WHERE MOCK_DATA_CLAIM.BEN_ID = @BEN_ID

UPDATE MOCK_DATA_CLAIM
SET MOCK_DATA_CLAIM.DTE_ADMISSION_UPDATE = @DTE_ADMISSION, MOCK_DATA_CLAIM.ID_UPDATE_DTE_ADD = @Id
WHERE MOCK_DATA_CLAIM.BEN_ID = @BEN_ID
AND ABS( DATEDIFF(DAY, @DTE_DISCHARGE, MOCK_DATA_CLAIM.DTE_ADMISSION) ) < 2

 END

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Id, @BEN_ID, @CLAIM_ID, @DTE_ADMISSION, @DTE_DISCHARGE
END

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

-- second code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MOCK_DATA_CLAIM_FINAL
SELECT a.BEN_ID, A.CLAIM_ID,
IIF(
    a.DTE_ADMISSION <> a.DTE_DISCHARGE,
    IIF(a.DTE_ADMISSION_UPDATE is not null, a.DTE_ADMISSION_UPDATE, a.DTE_ADMISSION),
    IIF(a.DTE_ADMISSION_UPDATE < a.DTE_DISCHARGE_UPDATE, a.DTE_ADMISSION_UPDATE, a.DTE_DISCHARGE_UPDATE)
) as DTE_ADMISSION,
IIF(
    a.DTE_ADMISSION <> a.DTE_DISCHARGE,
    IIF(a.DTE_DISCHARGE_UPDATE is not null, a.DTE_DISCHARGE_UPDATE, a.DTE_DISCHARGE),
    IIF( a.DTE_ADMISSION_UPDATE  < a.DTE_DISCHARGE_UPDATE or a.DTE_ADMISSION < a.DTE_DISCHARGE_UPDATE , a.DTE_DISCHARGE_UPDATE, a.DTE_ADMISSION)
) as DTE_DISCHARGE
INTO MOCK_DATA_CLAIM_FINAL
FROM MOCK_DATA_CLAIM a
order by a.BEN_ID, IIF(a.DTE_ADMISSION_UPDATE is not null, a.DTE_ADMISSION_UPDATE, a.DTE_ADMISSION)
```

Comment: Please provide the sample data as copied&pasted Text in the Question rather than an Image, and add a Tag for the D(atabase)B(ase)M(anagement)S(ystem) you are using, like for example `postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

**This is a classic *gaps-and-islands* problem.** There are a number of solutions to such a problem, I have provided one below.

You use `LAG` to get the previous row's value, then use a conditional windowed `COUNT` to number the groups, then use a windowed `MIN` and `MAX` to get the values across the group.

You can use an updatable CTE to actually make the update. Note that there are no self-joins, the table is only scanned once and there are no cursors.

```sql
WITH Prev AS (
    SELECT *,
      PrevDischarge = LAG(DTE_DISCHARGE, 1, '19000101') OVER (PARTITION BY BEN_ID ORDER BY DTE_ADMISSION)
    FROM MOCK_DATA_CLAIM
),
Counts AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(CASE WHEN PrevDischarge < DATEADD(day, -2, DTE_ADMISSION) THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY BEN_ID ORDER BY DTE_ADMISSION ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM Prev
),
MinMax AS (
    SELECT *,
      Min_ADMISSION = MIN(DTE_ADMISSION) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId),
      Max_DISCHARGE = MAX(DTE_DISCHARGE) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId)
    FROM Counts
)
UPDATE MinMax
SET DTE_ADMISSION = Min_ADMISSION,
    DTE_DISCHARGE = Max_DISCHARGE;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=79be569f2215426830cc008416635393)